# Auto retry on Video.js?

Tags: video.js

So, I am facing some issue with my Video.js player. I am using it to play HLS, but when the page loads, the .m3u8 is not available yet (another external service is starting it), and since I use autoplay, it fails to load because the request to m3u8 returns a 404.

Is there a way to tell video.js to keep trying? Video.js has a function called `onPlayerReady()` but it don't do what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting a fixed sleep time, so if the m3u8 isn't ready in 10sec I assume it will not load because of some issue with the source and then I stop the connection.